# WebStorm built-in web server gets 404 for every css and js file included in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, server, webstorm

Here is my index.html for posterity's sake:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <base href="/" />
    <title>Cart</title>
    <link href="content/external/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/external/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/external/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/external/angular-toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app>

{{3+4}}

drfg



<script src="scripts/external/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external/angular-animate.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I hit run in webstorm to open in chrome, I get a 404 for every single javascript and css file.  However, if I scope to the project directory and run node's `http-server`, my site loads just fine.  I can't seem to find anything in settings related to this.  Any ideas?

Comment: What URL is used when it fails? I bet it's something like `http://localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/index.html`. If so -- you are using WebStorm's own simple built-in web server. As you can see from URL it requires project name as first segment in path. Your `<base href="/" />` must be conflicting with that -- so it tries paths like `localhost:63342/content/external/bootstrap.css` which is wrong. Try without that tag.

Comment: Wow, you're totally right.  Thanks for pointing that out!  Want to submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is caused by  tag in index.html:

```
<base href="/"/>
```

that tells the browser to resolve all URLs in the page relative to the web server root (`localhost:63342` when using built-in webserver). Obviously no resources can be found there, as the built-in webserver serves files from `http://localhost:63342/<project root>`
So, you need to comment out '`<base href="/"/>`' to get your code working. Or, modify your hosts file to make webserver serve files from `http://<some name>:63342` - see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8988#comment=27-577559

Comment: Is it possible to change this behavior in webstorm?

Comment: please see above - you can modify the *hosts* file  to make webserver serve files from `http://<some name>:63342` - see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8988#comment=27-577559. or, just use a different webserver that can be set up to serve files from root

Comment: So the answer is "no"?  :)